# Periodically synching data from an API to database is extremely slow

Tags: python, performance, mysql, django, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task where I synch all the data from one table (via an API) to another. There are about 10,000 rows that are being updated and the new ones get created. This is what I came up with and for some reason, it is extremely slow.

```
def sync_data_from_hub():
    stats = tasks.sync_clients_from_hub()

    return stats
```

**tasks.py**

```
# 1. This method calls an external API to fetch all the rows.
def sync_clients_from_hub():
    url = resolve_hub_url('clients')

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('api response error: {}'.format(response))
        return

    try:
        response_payload = response.json()
    except ValueError:
        return

    # response from API
    clients_data = response_payload.get('data')

    for (key, value) in clients_data.items():
        # Check whether there are any actual changes in this row 
        # by comparing the last updated date
        if services.should_update_data_from_hub(value, constants.SyncTypes.CLIENT):
            user, action = services.update_or_create_client_from_hub_data(value)

            if action == constants.SyncActions.CRT:
                result['new'] += 1
            if action == constants.SyncActions.UPD:
                result['update'] += 1

    # soft delete clients which are not present in payload but still available in database.
    if clients_data:
        discarded_clients = models.Client.objects.exclude(pk__in=list(map(int, clients_data.keys()))).filter(
            is_active=True)

        for client in discarded_clients:
            client.is_active = False
            client.save()

            result['deleted'] += 1

    return result
```

**service.py**

```
# logic to determine whether we should update the row or not
def should_update_data_from_hub(hub_data: dict, sync_type: str) -> bool:
    last_updated_date_from_api = hub_data.get('updatedAt', None)

    hub_data['id'] = int(hub_data.get('client', ''))

    # This line hits DB to fetch the row corresponding to the one in the API
    entity = get_client_by_pk(hub_data['id'])

    if not entity:
        return True

    last_updated_date_local = entity.last_updated_date

    if not last_updated_date_local:
        return True
    # The last updated dates have different timezones, so I have to adjust the timezone before comparison.
    last_updated_date_tz = last_updated_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)

    last_updated_date_local_formatted = last_updated_date_tz.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    return last_updated_date_formatted != last_updated_date_from_api

# Actual method to update the data
def update_or_create_client_from_hub_data(client_data: dict):
    client_data['id'] = int(client_data.get('client', None))

    # Set `is_active` based on the `archived` flag.
    if client_data.get('archive', None) == '1':
        client_data['is_active'] = False
    else:
        client_data['is_active'] = True
    ...

    # Set `last_updated_date`
    client_data['last_updated_date'] = client_data.get('updatedAt', datetime.datetime.now())

    serializer = serializers.ClientCreateSerializer(data=client_data)

    if not serializer.is_valid():
        print('client sync errors: {}'.format(serializer.errors))
        return None, None

    # This line hits DB to fetch the row corresponding to the one in the API
    client = get_client_by_pk(serializer.validated_data['id'])

    if client:
        action = constants.SyncActions.UPD

        for (key, value) in serializer.validated_data.items():
            setattr(client, key, value)

        client.save()
    else:
        action = constants.SyncActions.CRT

        client = models.Client.objects.create(**serializer.validated_data)

    return client, action

def get_client_by_pk(pk: int) -> Optional[models.Client]:
    return models.Client.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
```

How can I optimize it to perform better? Should I load all the rows from DB in memory first rather than fetching them one by one and doing a comparison?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

### Error handling

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('api response error: {}'.format(response))
    return
```

is better represented as a simple call to `response.raise_for_status()`.

Also, this:

```
try:
    response_payload = response.json()
except ValueError:
    return
```

is dangerous. Silently failing should (at the least) be left up to the caller to decide whether an exception should be caught and swallowed, caught and printed, or allowed to fall through.

### Tuple unpacking

```
for (key, value) in clients_data.items():
```

can be

```
for key, value in clients_data.items():
```

### Undeclared variable

```
        if action == constants.SyncActions.CRT:
            result['new'] += 1
        if action == constants.SyncActions.UPD:
            result['update'] += 1
```

Where does `result` come from? You don't show this. Is it a `defaultdict`?

### Incorrect default

```
hub_data['id'] = int(hub_data.get('client', ''))
```

will not work in the case that the key is missing. You can't convert `''` to an `int`. Perhaps you meant:

```
hub_data['id'] = int(hub_data.get('client', '0'))
```

### Ellipses

This is more of a meta-comment, but

```
# Set `is_active` based on the `archived` flag.
if client_data.get('archive', None) == '1':
    client_data['is_active'] = False
else:
    client_data['is_active'] = True
...
```

should show the ellipses as a comment to avoid breaking syntactical validity, and you should provide rationale as to why this code is elided. Eliding code harms the potential for you to receive a meaningful review.

### Optimization

> How can I optimize it to perform better?

It's nearly impossible to say. You haven't run a profiler, which you should; you've elided too much code for us to run this thing; you haven't shown any example data; and you haven't given us an API endpoint (or if that's not possible, at least a sample of a payload the endpoint would return).